# Show that $|x|^{\alpha} \in H^1(\Omega)$, for $\alpha >0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I wish to show that

$|x|^{\alpha} \in H^1(\Omega)$, for $\alpha >0$,

where $\Omega$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I tried switching to polar coordinates, but I do not get the result I am after. In particular I have the following integral

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} r^{2\alpha + 1} \ dr d\theta$

Is this integral correct to show that the function is square integrable? I also need to show that each of the first order partials are square integrable as well.

Comment: I think you mean "polar", not "cylindrical". Yes, the finiteness of that integral is fine to show the function is square integrable, but it's easier than that: any bounded function on the unit disc is square integrable there.

Comment: The issue that I have is with the parameter $\alpha$. When I evaluate the above I arrive at a finite quantity irrespective of the value of $\alpha$ which is wrong.

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion? Clearly the value of the integral depends on $\alpha.$

Comment: It is clear that the integral is finite for $\alpha$ positive, so I then looked to the case of negative values where I became confused.

Comment: Take $\alpha = 0$ in the above for example. That integral is finite...

Comment: Why do you care about nonpositive values of $\alpha?$ The hypothesis is  $\alpha > 0.$

Comment: I wanted to consider all the cases if possible, not just solve the problem as stated.

Comment: We can't tell what you want. We can only see what you ask about.

Comment: $\|x\|^a$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$ for $a > -1$, since $\int_{\|x\| < 1} |\|x\|^a|^2 dx = 2 \pi \int_0^1 r |r^a|^2 dr = 2 \pi \int_0^1 r^{1+2a} dr$ which converges whenever $a > -1$. hence $f(x) = \|x\|^a$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$ whenever $f$ and $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right| \le \frac{\partial f}{\partial \|x\|} = a \|x\|^{a-1}$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$, i.e. whenever $a > 0$.

Comment: That seems to be what the problem was asking for. Thanks.